# Collision detection with multiple centre-coordinated rectangles (C++)

Tags: c++, coordinates, collision-detection, collision, maze

I am making a maze game and I would like to implement perfect collision detection between the character (which is a square, size: 0.2 × 0.2) and the walls (which are made from rectanges, size: 0.25 × 1). The most important thing is that the coordinates which define the positions (which are x and z) are in the centre, at the middle of the objects, not at the corners. I simply can't find out how this would work. So far I've got a function which works almost perfectly but it expects that the coordinates are at the corners.

I'd like to know how to modify the function to detect collision based on the information I've provided above. Thank you in advance!

```
bool IsCollide(Cube character, std::vector<Cube> maze)
{
bool collided = false;
for (auto i : maze)
    if (i.position.z < character.position.z + character.size.z &&
        i.position.z + i.size.z > character.position.z&&
        i.position.x < character.position.x + character.size.x &&
        i.size.x + i.position.x > character.position.x)
    {

        collided = true;
        return collided;
    } return collided;
}
```

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this kind of a thing. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using brief, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: Who said that asking a question is something to be ashamed of? I don't know about you, but I talk to my rubber duck all the time whenever I have a question about my code. It's always a very helpful conversation.